# Display Element only when on Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, onscroll

I have a Navaigation bar that i want to get fixed at the top only when the user scrolls the page to about 100px.

Which is the best way to achieve this?

http://play.mink7.com/sophiance/

Comment: best way is to search for sticky navigation bar

Comment: @roasted i have created sticky bar. but want it to appear only after scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 100) {

          //when page scrolls past 100px

        } else {

          //when page within 100px

        }
    });
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Working DEMO here...http://jsfiddle.net/eFCK3/1/

## HTML

```
<div id="header-small">Header</div>
<div>
    <p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#header-small{
    display:none;background:red;padding:2%;position:fixed;top:0px;width:960%;    
}
```

$JQUERY

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>100) {
        $('#header-small').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#header-small').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a scroll-Handler using jQuery. 
`$("html, body").scroll(yourHandler() {});`
Then simply check for the scroll-position via
 `$("html, body").scrollTop();`
Determine if that is scrolled as far as you want it to go and then add a css-Class to the navigation bar which adds the fixed-attribute for example or something more complex if you desire.

Don´t forget to remove the class or any other changes you did again if the scrolls back again.

Answer (score 1):

This will stick the navigation top the top of window the moment it reaches the top.Hope it helps.

```
 var $window = $(window),
           $navigation = $('#navigation'),
           elTop = $navigation.offset().top;

       $window.scroll(function() {
            $navigation.toggleClass('fixed', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
        });
```

Comment: where should i set the 100px ?

Comment: you just place your navigation where  you want , it can be at any distance from top, 100 in this case, then put the above code in your script and it automatically sticks to top when it reaches there.